# Wordpress More tag is not working on home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently working on integrating wordpress with my website, but I'm hitting a wall here.

I need the initial blog page(basically just the index.php of WP) to pick up the `<!--more-->` quicktags, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've followed the WP Codex, but that didn't help me at all.

So here's part of the template file: content.php

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
            }
        the_excerpt(); 

        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="bthumb2">
        <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail(array(220, 130));
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
            the_content("READ MORE"); 
        ?>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'tinfoilhats' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But it just keeps displaying the `<!--more-->` tag in the posts once I load the page.

I've tried it with the global $more thing, but that didn't work for me.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
            global $more;
            $more = 0;

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `global $more` example looks good, and almost follows the recommendation on the [documentation page applicable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) (the `global $more` line itself is supposed to be outside "the loop" - before `while ( have_posts() )` - leaving the next line where it is.)

However, I couldn't get this to work on my own blog (using a a child theme of Coraline) until I moved *both* lines to before "the loop".  Starting with your code, I'd suggest something like this:

```
<?php
    global $more;
    $more = 0;
?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```